# Exception: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'File?'

Tags: flutter

I have a function that returns an image, and another variable initialized as null. but when I call the function and update the state of the variable to get the returned image of the function I get this error :

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'File?'

```
Future ff(String styleImagePath, String originalImagePath) async {
  ImageTransferFacade showtime = ImageTransferFacade();
  showtime.loadModel();
  var style_image =
      await showtime.loadStyleImage('assets/Tableau_Dashboard.jpg');
  var original_image =
      await showtime.loadoriginalImage('assets/Tableau_Dashboard.jpg');

  var output_image = await showtime.transfer(original_image, style_image);
  output_image = Image.memory(output_image);
  return output_image;
}

File? finalsd = null;
// This is where I'll use the 'finalsd' variable , but if I change type to Image instead of File
    child: Card(
                      child: (finalsd == null)
                          ? Image.file(File(_image.path))
                          : Image.file(File(finalsd!
                              .path)))))
```

Error emerges here :

```
child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    ff(imageList[index], widget.image.path).then((value) {
                      setState(() {
                        finalsd = value;
```

Comment: Can you please show more of your code? Where are you using the returned `output_image` variable? Showing the fill GestureDetector widget would be helpful

Comment: The error message is self explanatory i think. You are returning an  `Image` and assigning it to a variable of type `File`. Both types are not related and thus the error is thrown.

Comment: @Roaa the returned image is the 'value' inside GestureDetector widget

Comment: I meant the place where you use the `finalsd` variable

Comment: Please review my edit  , if i changed `finalsd` type to Image , I'll get an error since I'm trying to display the image as if it were a file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method returns a `Future` containing the type `Image`. After resolving the `Future` in your `GestureDetector` you are assigning it to a variable of type `File`. Both types are not related and thus the error is thrown.

```
output_image = Image.memory(output_image);
return output_image;
```

This creates and returns an `Image` and you are assigning it to this variable:

```
File? finalsd = null;
```

Dart would probably also warn you about this if you would declare the generic type in the return type of your method:

```
Future<Image> ff(String styleImagePath, String originalImagePath) async {
```

Comment: so I should declare it like that instead ?  `Image ? finalsd = null;`

Comment: Yes. If an `Image` type is what you need

Comment: I think it solves this issue, but then I get another error since I'm using the output as if it were a file, not an image ! could you please how can I solve this in the updated code

Comment: Why don't you directly use `finalsd` in the updated Code instead of creating a new Image from a file path? so instead of `Image.file(File(finalsd! .path))`, just use `finalsd` since it already has the correct type.